# Best way to reuse C# code to pass system.servicemodel.security.usernamepasswordclientcredential credentials to different class files

Tags: c#, code-reuse

I'm a beginner at writing and understanding C#. I would like to know how to reuse some code I have that updates a WebService username and password credentials.

Here is code in 1st cs File:
...

```
public class AuthenticateLogin
{

    public static object PassCredentials()
    {
        ServiceName.UsersClient clientauthentication = new ServiceName.UsersClient();
        clientauthentication.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
        clientauthentication.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pwd";
    }
}
```

...

Here is code in 2nd cs File:

```
var test =  AuthenticateLogin.PassCredentials();
Console.WriteLine(test.EchoAuthenticated("Successful Login"));
```

Error Received:
Error   CS1061  'AuthenticateLogin' does not contain a definition for 'EchoAuthenticated' and no accessible extension method 'EchoAuthenticated' accepting a first argument of type 'AuthenticateLogin' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Solution desired:

In the second file, I want to be able to use the methods in the 'clientauthentication' of the first file. I need to be able to use the 'clientauthentication' like a common object in multiple other cs files. FYI: I can use the 'clientauthentication' methods fine in the 1st file and it works okay.

Comment: Where is EchoAuthenticated defined?

Comment: It is defined in a public partial class in the WebService called UsersClient. It looks like this:  public partial class UsersClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ServiceName.IUsers>, ServiceName.IUsers {
        
        public string EchoAuthenticated(string value) {
            return base.Channel.EchoAuthenticated(value);
        }             }

Comment: `PassCredentials` is missing a `return` statement. Assuming it returns `clientauthentication` you need to cast `test` to a `UsersClient` before you can call `EchoAuthenticated` on it

Comment: @ iakobski - i get the terminology mixed up. Do you mean instantiate a new UsersClient class for 'test'.?

Comment: You *are* creating a new `UsersClient` object when you call `PassCredentials`. The code you have shown does not compile. I am assuming, and I may be wrong, that the last line of `PassCredentials` is `return clientauthentication;` When this is assigned to `test` in the second snippet, the `var` resolves to `object` as that's the return type of `PassCredentials`. The compiler only knows that it's an object at that point, so you can't call any methods on it other than those defined for `object`. So you need to tell the compiler that it's actually a `UsersClient` using a cast: `(UsersClient)test`.

Comment: For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

Comment: If my assumption is wrong, you need to post the actual code you have.